# Sequential approximate diagonal

Tags: banach-algebras, amenability

Let $A$ be a unital, amenable Banach algebra.

> What is the significance of $A$ to have a weakly Cauchy *sequential* approximate diagonal?

A preliminary observation: Let $\displaystyle A\hat{\otimes}_{\pi} A$ denote the twofold projective tensor product. If $(\texttt{m}_n)$ in $\displaystyle A\hat{\otimes}_{\pi} A$ is a weakly Cauchy sequential approximate diagonal, then by Rosenthal's $c_0$ theorem [Theorem 1.1, [Rosenthal1994](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-1994-1242455-4)], either $A\hat{\otimes}_{\pi} A$ contains a copy of $c_0$, or $(\texttt{m}_n)$ contains a strongly summing subsequence. Thus, the question above takes another form:

> What is the significance of $A$ to have a (bounded) *sequential* approximate diagonal, which is strongly summing?

---

*footnote:* pls. see [[Runde2002](https://doi.org/10.1007/b82937), [p.44](https://books.google.ca/books?id=gUJ7CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA44)] for the definition of approximate diagonal.)